# What should org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.getResponseBodyAsString() return?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to use `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()` and get the body response but I get the following string

> {"status":"OK","message":"","body":
>   [{"id":"2AXE167H3","name":"spark","group":"spark","properties":{"spark.cores.max":"","spark.yarn.jar":"","master":"local[*]","zeppelin.spark.maxResult":"1000","zeppelin.dep.localrepo":"local-repo","spark.app.name":"Zeppelin","spark.executor.memory":"512m","zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext":"true","zeppelin.spark.concurrentSQL"....

I was expecting just the body part...
Other method such as `getStatusCode()` return the actual status

Any help?

Comment: Ever considered that this `JSON` might be actual body from the response?

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, response was built using this code: ```public javax.ws.rs.core.Response build() {
    ResponseBuilder r = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(status).entity(this.toString());
    if (cookies != null) {
      for (NewCookie nc : cookies) {
        r.cookie(nc);
      }
    }
    return r.build();
  }``` 
and the toString() method just build the JSON part of the body